# Python IDE to auto-refactor duplicate code

Tags: python, ide, abstraction, code-duplication

Say I am in the middle of writing series of commands and decide I want to turn it into a for loop. For instance say I have

```
print('Jane','Bennet')
print('Elizabeth','Bennet')
print('Mary','Bennet')
```

to start with and I decide I want to turn it into a for loop:

```
for s in ['Jane','Elizabeth','Mary']:
   print(s,'Bennet')
```

or possibly even a list comprehension:

```
[print(s,'Bennet') for s in ['Jane','Elizabeth','Mary']]
```

Is there a Python IDE that can convert between these forms automatically? Or maybe there are other tools that can do this?

Comment: As a side not, this list comprehension would build a list of `None`. You should use comprehensions to build lists, not for the side effects of the functions that get called inside - that is better expressed in normal loops.

Comment: I’m sure you could find a way to do something like this in most editors, although it might requires scripting/plugins/etc. Is this really that much of a concern?

Comment: A script or plugin for an existing IDE would be a perfect fit for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, the list comprehension shown is a bad example. A better one would be to convert `[f('Jane','Bennet'), f('Elizabeth','Bennet'), f('Mary','Bennet')]` into `[f(s,'Bennet') for s in ['Jane','Elizabeth','Mary']]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend the list comprehension refactor. It would be harder to read as list comprehensions are intended strictly as a concise notation for the iterative generation of a list. If your editor has a rectangular selection feature, you can do this:

```
# First tab the sirnames out away from the given names. (They don't need to be neatly
# aligned like this, you can just copy paste a bunch of spaces.)
print('Jane',         'Bennet')
print('Elizabeth',    'Bennet')
print('Mary',         'Bennet')
```

```
# Use rectangular selection to get rid of the sir names and the print statements,
# leaving the commas. An editor like Geany will also allow you to get rid of the
# trailing whitespace, making your code easier to navigate.
'Jane',
'Elizabeth',
'Mary',
```

```
# Add a variable initialization followed by square brackets around the given names.
# You can also pretty it up by indenting or deleting newlines as you see fit.
givenNames = [
  'Jane',
  'Elizabeth',
  'Mary',
]
```

```
# Add your for loop.
givenNames = [
  'Jane',
  'Elizabeth',
  'Mary',
]
for name in givenNames:
    print(f"{name} bennet")
```